# Using holdout cross validation in the inner loop of nested cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Is it valid to do a k-fold CV in the outer loop of a nested CV but use the holdout method in the inner loop to avoid computational complexity?

My guess is that one could leave one of the k sets out in the inner CV loop so that he could run a k-1 cross validation on the sets left where each fold would have a different validation set.

**For example, if one is running a 4-fold CV in the outer loop then the dataset would initially be split like this (each number denotes the respective fold):**

1st set

- training set: 1-2-3
- test set: 4

2nd set

- training set: 2-3-4
- test set: 1

3rd set

- training set: 1-3-4
- test set: 2

4th set

- training set: 1-2-4
- test set: 3

**Then, for the 3 fold CV the data would look like this:**

1st set

- training set: 3-4
- validation set: 2

2nd set

- training set: 2-4
- validation set: 3

3rd set

- training set: 1-3
- validation set: 4

So, to tune the set of hyperparameters one could test the model using the holdout method in each of the 3 sets and then just use the hyperparameters that performed better (on average) to test the model in the outer CV loop.

I assume that this is of course less accurate than a normal nested k-fold cross validation especially given low values of k. However, for higher values of k and bigger datasets would this result in a good trade-off between accuracy and computational complexity?